# how to specify, in nodejs file: URL, a absolute path under windows

Tags: node.js, windows, url

I use node.js `URL` class to parse different user URLs, no problem with usual protocols and no problem with `file:` urls under linux.

But I have found a problem with `file:` under windows when the user tries to specify an absolute path like `file://C:\temp\test.jpg`

```
> u = new URL('file://C:\\temp\\test.jpg');
URL {
  href: 'file:///C:/temp/test.jpg',
  origin: 'null',
  protocol: 'file:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: '',
  hostname: '',
  port: '',
  pathname: '/C:/temp/test.jpg',
  search: '',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
  hash: ''
}
```

you can see the `u.pathname` is `'/C:/temp/test.jpg'`, note the leading `/`, making the pathname useless.

what is the correct way to specify in an URL in nodejs for an absolute path to a windows file?

Comment: Why is the windows path escaped? Have you tried without double backslash?

Comment: @Marc inside a javascript string you need to use double backslash for backslash, if not, the single backslash will be interpreted as a escape char

Comment: My bad. My brain was not working ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlfileurltopathurl

```
new URL('file:///C:/path/').pathname;      // Incorrect: /C:/path/
fileURLToPath('file:///C:/path/');         // Correct:   C:\path\ (Windows)
```